# Add shadow to a border

Tags: html, css

As you can see I've created a sideBar:

```
<div id="sideBar">
<button class="button">Home</button><br>
<button class="button">About Me</button><br>
<button class="button">Gallery</button><br>
<button class="button">Contact</button>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <p>Content Div</p>
</div>
```

My css:

```
#sideBar {
background-color: grey;
width: 200px;
float: left;
height: 200px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset -16px 0px 10px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: inset -16px 0px 10px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: inset -16px 0px 10px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.button {
background-color: grey;
border-width: 0 0 2px 0;
border-color: white;
border-style: solid;
color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset -16px 0px 10px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: inset -16px 0px 10px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: inset -16px 0px 10px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
width: 200px;
}

#content {
background-color: white;
color: black;
float: left;
width: 200px;
border: 1px solid black;
height: 200px;
}

#content p {
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/of4dcp2u/1/

I've used some inner shadow. The only problem is that I can't get the shadow work in de border lines. The white borders don't have any shadow.

I don't want to use any images for buttons. Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sam, Put shadow to the content div like this

```
.button {
    background-color: grey;
    border-width: 0 0 2px 0;
    border-color: white;
    border-style: solid;
    color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
    cursor: pointer;

    width: 200px;
}

#content {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 200px;
     -webkit-box-shadow: -16px 0px 10px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: -16px 0px 10px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: -16px 0px 10px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `box-shadow` you have set to `.button` is going in the wrong direction. Use this code:

```
.button {
    background-color: grey;
    border-width: 0 0 2px 0;
    border-color: white;
    border-style: solid;
    color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 16px 10px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 16px 10px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 16px 10px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    width: 200px;
}
```